# Is it possible to predict whether using a temporarily moved ally as a proxy target for an enemy that isn't there yet will work?

Tags: disgaea

In Disgaea, there are several uses for a temporarily moved ally.

The one of interest for this question is using them as a proxy target for an attack on an enemy that isn't there yet because an earlier attack in the combo is a fist special that will move the enemy there.

This is how to set it up:

1. Move ally A into position and order them to perform fist special on enemy.
2. Move ally B to the square where ally A's fist special will displace the enemy.
3. Move ally C into position and order them to attack ally B.
4. Undo ally B's move.
5. Execute orders.

Sometimes it works - ally A performs their fist special, displaces the enemy to the target square for ally C's attack, and ally C continues the combo with their attack, now against the enemy instead of ally B whom it originally targetted.

Sometimes it doesn't work - ally A performs their fist special, displaces the enemy to the target square for ally C's attack, but ally C doesn't make any attack at all and the combo is cut short.

Is there any way to predict whether or not it will work?